# How to use map instead of list comprehension (Haskell)

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I have made this code which replaces all elements from a list which fulfilss a predicate:

```
gRep :: (t -> Bool) -> t -> [t] -> [t]
gRep pred x ys = [if pred y then x else y | y <- ys]
```

so f.eks I get these outputs:

```
ghci> gRep (<'g') 'z' "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
"zzzzzzghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
ghci> gRep (<3) 0 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[0,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

How can I write this function using map instead?

I tried to write it like this:

```
gRepMap :: (t -> Bool) -> t -> [t] -> [t]
gRepMap pred x ys = map (\zs -> if (pred y) then x else y | y <- ys) ys
```

But I get a parser-error because of `| y <- ys` . I know this may be a possible duplicate, but I couldnt find a question which dealt with this particular conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable in the lamba expession `\zs -> …` is `zs` this variable will ues the elements in the list, since the lambda expression is called with each element of th elist, as a result you thus perform the mapping with:

```
gRepMap :: (t -> Bool) -> t -> [t] -> [t]
gRepMap pred x ys = map (\zs -> if pred zs then x else zs) ys
```

Usually in Haskell a variable name ends with an `s` to denote a *collection* of items (especially when working with lists). Here `zs` is an element of that list, it thus makes more sense to name the variable `y` or `z`, not <s>`zs`</s>:

```
gRepMap :: (t -> Bool) -> t -> [t] -> [t]
gRepMap pred x ys = map (\y -> if pred y then x else y) ys
```

Answer (score 2):

```
gRep    pred x ys = [           if (pred y) then x else y | y <- ys]
--                                                         ^^^ ------>>>--.
gRepMap pred x ys = map (\ y -> if (pred y) then x else y )      ys   --  |
                          ^^^ <----------<<<--------------<<<-------------*
```

That's how it works for *any* expression in the *output* section of  [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/list-comprehension/info), according to the [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11), which gives an equivalent translation,

```
 [ exp |     y <-        ys ]
===
 concatMap (\y -> [exp]) ys
===
 map       (\y ->  exp ) ys
```

The Report gives a more general translation which is equivalent to the above in the case of irrefutable pattern, like `y` is here.

The `| y <- ys` bit belongs to the list comprehension syntax, you shouldn't have copied it there. Instead, `y` becomes the lambda parameter, and `ys` is the list being mapped over.